# how do we maintain referential integrity without using primary key and foreign key

Tags: mysql, referential-integrity

i have created function like below, but showing error. any ideas are welcome.

```
CREATE FUNCTION `CheckFunction`() RETURNS varchar(36) 
BEGIN
RETURN (select DISTINCT column from table);
END
```

> Error: Error Code: 3814.  An expression of a check constraint 'CheckFunction'
> contains disallowed function: CheckFunction

Comment: From [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-check-constraints.html) *"CHECK condition expressions must adhere to the following rules. An
> error occurs if an expression contains disallowed constructs. ... **Stored functions and user-defined functions are not permitted.**"*

Comment: got it, Thank you,

Comment: could you let me know, is there any approach to maintain referential integrity without using PK and FK.

Comment: Why not using FK?

Comment: as part history maintenance, we cant define primary key as the values will be repeating. so this reason we are not able to give PK and FK.